# How to update dates in a table so that each row's date is pushed ahead by 1 day?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table whose Date column needs pushing ahead by 1 day.

My update query is:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET DATECOL=DATECOL+1
```

Is this correct approach? Or do I need to use CTE, for example:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ID, DATECOL
FROM TABLENAME)
UPDATE T
SET T.DATECOL=CTE.DATECOL+1
FROM TABLENAME T
JOIN CTE ON T.ID=CTE.ID
```

Comment: [Basic searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=add+date+sql+server&oq=add+date+sql+server) yields [`DATEADD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql). Come on, please. Anyway you can't possibly have even _tried_ the code you show because `+1` is not a valid operation for `date`, and you would already know it is _not_ the correct approach.

Comment: I'm trying to get the algorithm right, that was the purpose of this question, that is - whether it needs direct UPDATE vs UPDATE VIA CTE.

Comment: Why would you think your convoluted CTE is necessary to update a column directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a value to any part of date you can use DATEADD function. In your case the part time is DAY.

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET DATECOL=DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATECOL)
```